# Load external Google Fonts stylesheet with YepNope/Modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, modernizr, yepnope

I'm trying to load a dynamically generated Google Font stylesheet using Modernizr (YepNope)  but always get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL (css:1)

My stylesheet looks like this:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Holtwood+One+SC
```

and I'm calling it via

```
Modernizr.load({
    load: ['css!http://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Holtwood+One+SC|Terminal+Dosis:700'],
    callback: 
        function (url, result, key) {
            console.log('loaded...!');          
        }       
});
```

The website says this but for some reason it just won't work. I think the resource is parsed as a script file and that's what cause the error, but can't seem to make it work =(

> "With the css! prefix, you can prepend it to any file name and yepnope
>   will treat it like a css file."

Anyone had success achieving something similar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are adding the css prefix file to your copy of yepnope. It works like a jQuery plugin.

You can get it at:

https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/prefixes/yepnope.css-prefix.js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! Great job on the loader by the way =)

Comment: Would there be a way to integrate those plugins (prefix + css wait) in a Modernizr build ?

Comment: If you just append them to the end of the modernizr file, they'll work like a charm. (for some definition of 'charm')

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can call Google Webfont API, such as:

```
Modernizr.load({
 load: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js',
 complete: function () {

  WebFont.load({
   google: {
    families: ['Open+Sans:300,400,700']
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Ideally should also have use a no-js fallback to load the fonts from your server using a timed function or another, like:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
 Modernizr.load('http://d.clickmetrics.cl/assets/js/scaffolding/jquery-1.9.0.min.js');
}
```