# How can I load dynamically typekit fonts?

Tags: css, embedded-fonts, typekit

Is there a way to load typekit fonts dynamically, much like the Google Font API?

That is, how can I declare **dynamically** on each page the font name in a css link and load just the font(s) that are required for that page, instead of adding fonts into a kit and the loading the whole kit.

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670298/load-external-google-fonts-stylesheet-with-yepnope-modernizr

Comment: @rlb-usa: The link you provide discusses Google Fonts that can load dynamically (they support this functionality). This is not the case with Typekit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, posting it here in case it is useful for someone else:

I will use the Typekit API to dynamically create a new 'kit' (i.e. javascript file) for every different combination that my app requires, instead of including all of them in one big 'kit'.

See: https://typekit.com/docs/api/kits

Thanks anyway for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a server side script that, depending on the page, will generate a different css file with the *font-family* rule(s) you wish.
Then you could use  *@import* to bring this rule into your main css file.

Answer (score 0):

TypeKit has recently introduced a way that users may find useful to perform functionality similar to what you are looking for but doing it in a very easy way without having to use the API. They call it [Dynamic Subsetting](http://blog.typekit.com/2015/06/15/announcing-east-asian-web-font-support/).

As I write this it is only available for East Asian Fonts, however, there is a workaround to use it with other TypeKit fonts. The workaround comes from [this site](http://www.iamtomnewton.com/blog/dynamic-typography/).

1. Add a East Asian Font such as Source Han Sans Japanese. This will automatically convert the kit to a dynamic kit.
2. Select each font and under the `Character Set` options choose `Dynamic Subsetting` for each font.
3. Remove the East Asian Font.
4. Publish Kit.

Even if you remove the East Asian Font, the kit will remain a Dynamic Kit.